# How to remove illegal characters from nodejs buffer?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got a base64 encoded string of a csv file from frontend. In backend i am converting base64 string to binary and then trying to convert it to json object.

```
 var csvDcaData = new Buffer(source, 'base64').toString('binary')//convert base64 to binary
```

Problem is, Ui is sending some illegal characters with on of the field which are not visible to user in plain csv. "ï»¿" these are characters appended in one of csv field.

I want to remove these kind of characters from data from base64 but i am not able to recognize them in buffer, after conversion these characters appear.

It is possible in any way to detect such kind of characters from buffer.

Comment: I suppose you don't want `.toString('binary')` then, but rather `.toString('utf8')`   (or whatever encoding was used on the frontend)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source is sending you a message. The message consists of metadata and text. The first few bytes of the message are identifiable as metadata because they are the Byte-Order Mark (BOM) encoded in UTF-8. That strongly suggests that the text is encoded in UTF-8. Nonetheless, to read the text you should find out from the sender which encoding is used.

Yes, the BOM "characters" should be stripped off when wanting to deal only in the text. They are not characters in the sense that they are not part of the text. (Though, if you decode the bytes as UTF-8, it matches the codepoint U+FEFF.)

So, though perhaps esoteric, the message does not contain illegal characters but actually has useful metadata.

Also, given that you are not stripping off the BOM, the fact that you are seeing "ï»¿" instead of "﻿" (U+FEFF ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE) means that you are not using UTF-8 to decode the text. That could result in data loss. There is no text but encoded text. You always have to know and use the correct encoding.

---

Now, `source` is a JavaScript string (which, by-the-way, uses the UTF-16 encoding of Unicode). The content of the string is a message encoded in Base64. The message is a sequence of bytes which are the UTF-8 encoding of a BOM and text. You want the text in a JavaScript string. (And the text happens to be some form of CSV. For that, you'll need to know the line ending, delimiter, and text-qualifier.) There is a lot for you and the sender to talk about. Perhaps the sender has documented all this.

```
const stripBom = require('strip-bom');

const original = "¡You win one million ₹! Now you can get a real ";
const base64String = Buffer.from("\u{FEFF}" + original, "utf-8").toString("base64");
console.log(base64String);

const decodedString = 
    stripBom(Buffer.from(base64String, "base64").toString("utf-8"));

console.log(decodedString);
console.log(original === decodedString);
```